# paypal - how to split payment for digital goods

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I guess my question is not very specific, but still I am not sure about the answer.

I have a platform that allows individual sellers to sell digital goods.

I need to implement a payment flow, which will allow to split payment into 2 parts: commission for the platform and the rest for the seller.

Also I should not receive sellers money on my bank account, I can receive only my commission fee.

Is that possible to implement with adaptive payments chained flow? Or maybe any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly what a chained payment is.  Details available [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/).